# How to get the first line from cmd command output?

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

I need to get only first line from Windows cmd command.

Example of command:

```
dir /b /o-d cert*.pem
```

it returns:

```
cert1.pem
cert2.pem
cert3.pem
```

How to get only first line to return `cert1.pem`?

Operational System: Windows 10

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Return the command from a language and try to split the string using break line. But is not a good way

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should do it:

```ps1
dir /b /o-d cert*.pem > temp.txt && for /l %l in (1,1,1) do @for /f "tokens=1,2* delims=:" %a in ('findstr /n /r "^" temp.txt ^| findstr /r "^%l:"') do @echo %b
```

Bonus in **[powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell)**:

```ps1
Get-ChildItem hello*.txt | select -first 1
```

Comment: you saved the result in a temp file but didn't delete it which isn't good. But you don't even need a temp file to achieve the purpose

Answer (score 8):

You only need 2 short lines in batch

```bat
@echo off

for /f "tokens=* usebackq" %%f in (`dir /b /o:d`) do (set "file=%%f" & goto :next)
:next

echo %file%
```

The `goto` will break out of the loop after the first iteration. The result is stored in `%file%`

However this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/230282) because **you don't actually need to get the *first* line**!!! Just invert the sorting order (`o:d` to `o:-d`) and get the *last* line which can be done easily with a simple **single liner**

```bat
@for /f "tokens=* usebackq" %%f in (`dir /b /o:-d`) do @set "file=%%f"
```

---

In PowerShell you just need to run `(Get-ChildItem)[0]`, or its aliases `(ls)[0]` or `(dir)[0]`. Or if you want just the names then

```bat
(dir)[0].Name       # base name only, or
(dir)[0].FullName   # for full name including path
```

Comment: I am using a wmic process in the backticks but my file variable isn't populated. Any idea why? `wmic process where "ProcessId=%PID%" get ExecutablePath`

Comment: @ParthShah please ask a different question on that